# How to convert NSString to NSDate object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I am receiving TimeString from server in such format - `"2012-04-23T14:00:00.511Z"` and for some reason I get `nil` when trying to convert that into NSDate object by doing following

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"2012-04-23T14:00:00.511Z"];
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Your format string is wrong.  Check the documentation.

Comment: do you see the `T` inside your string? I do not see any match in the format string for that. Additionally there are whitespaces, milliseconds, etc.

Comment: even if i use @"yyyy-MM-dd" format string, it returns nil

Comment: Did you read our comments? *How* is `"yyyy-MM-dd"` supposed to match the string?????

Comment: Ok, i got it, seems like i have nothing to do with that, rather than asking for correct timeformat string from the server.

Comment: Or you could change the time format string?  What would be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like,

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: @"2012-04-23T14:00:51Z"];
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I figured this out lately. Sorry for not upvoting, previous guys lowered my rating by downvoting my question, and i am now eligible even to upvote and save good answers for myself :)

Comment: you're welcome.... :) If it is work and you feel that it is helping then accept the answer so other people having similar issue can use it... :)